# Multiple polygon edit in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make plot that it has two polygon patches over it. I want to use the example given in Matplotlib.org web page called PloygonInteractor. My code as follows;

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def dist(x, y):
    """
    Return the distance between two points.
    """
    d = x - y
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(d, d))


def dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1):
    """
    Get the distance of a point to a segment.
      *p*, *s0*, *s1* are *xy* sequences
    This algorithm from
    http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html
    """
    v = s1 - s0
    w = p - s0
    c1 = np.dot(w, v)
    if c1 <= 0:
        return dist(p, s0)
    c2 = np.dot(v, v)
    if c2 <= c1:
        return dist(p, s1)
    b = c1 / c2
    pb = s0 + b * v
    return dist(p, pb)


class PolygonInteractor:
    """
    A polygon editor.

    Key-bindings

      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them

      'd' delete the vertex under point

      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices

    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure '
                               'or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly

        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y,
                           marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                           animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)

        self.cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.on_draw)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_button_release)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def on_draw(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        # do not need to blit here, this will fire before the screen is
        # updated

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        """This method is called whenever the pathpatch object is called."""
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        """
        Return the index of the point closest to the event position or *None*
        if no point is within ``self.epsilon`` to the event position.
        """
        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
        indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
        ind = indseq[0]

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button presses."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button releases."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Callback for key presses."""
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'd':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = np.delete(self.poly.xy,
                                         ind, axis=0)
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key == 'i':
            xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
            p = event.x, event.y  # display coords
            for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i + 1]
                d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                if d <= self.epsilon:
                    self.poly.xy = np.insert(
                        self.poly.xy, i+1,
                        [event.xdata, event.ydata],
                        axis=0)
                    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                    break
        if self.line.stale:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse movements."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
        if self._ind == 0:
            self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
        elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
            self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


x1 = np.array([-1.5, -1.5, -1.0, -1.0])
y1 = np.array([-1.0, -1.5, -1.5, -1.0])
poly1 = Polygon(np.column_stack([x1, y1]),  color='gray', fill=False, animated=True)

x2 = np.array([-1.5, -1.5, -1.0, -1.0])
y2 = np.array([ 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0])
poly2 = Polygon(np.column_stack([x2, y2]), color='b', fill=False, animated=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(poly1)
ax.add_patch(poly2)

p1 = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly1)
p2 = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly2)

ax.set_xlim((-2, 2))
ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))
plt.show()
```

and this creates a plot like this:
[image: my plot]

My problem is that when trying to adjust polygon 2 (bottom), polygon 1 (upper) disappears. What should I do for this?

Comment: What is the problem again ? I tried you code and it did work fine. [Test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COxXr.png) & [Test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1VGu.png).

Comment: Impossible for me, when I tried firstly to move bottom patch points, upper patch disappering. On the other hand, when I tried firstly to move upper patch, everything is okay, but when tried secondly to move bottom patch points, upper patch again disappering. It is very strange. I wonder if this is related with the version of matplotlib or something else?

Comment: Did you try to move the points of patch with left mouse click?

Comment: Have you noticed that the red points of polygons are draggable points?